# Having bit of Oil problem

Tags: ford, starting, oil, mustang

I have a 2000 Ford Mustang,the oil light came up, so I thought it's time to put some oil in it. I did that and my oil light still says on. I am feeling low as my car won't start. Any clue what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The oil light is not a tool to tell you when to put oil in. **The oil light is a warning that something serious is wrong.**

Oil is used to lubricate the engine and must circulate while running. The light indicates there is insufficient oil pressure in the system to prevent damage. If you did not shut the engine off immediately after the light came on, you likely caused serious damage to your engine.

There are a few things that will cause low oil pressure (light to turn on).

1. Low/no oil in the engine - If there isn't enough oil in the pan for
   the pump to pick it up, you will lose pressure.
2. Bad oil pump - these can go bad, typically if the engine is worn or
   poorly maintained.
3. Poorly maintained or worn engine - engines with bad bearings and/or
   sludge build up can have low oil pressure.
4. Defective oil pressure sending unit - it is possible the device that
   monitors oil pressure is bad.

If the light stays on, don't run the engine, and have it towed to a shop so a mechanic look at it.